# Multiple excel worksheets to PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

All,

I have the below code which copies multiple worksheets in excel and exports them to a PDF worksheet. One worksheet per PDF page, I would like to know if it is possible to have two worksheets on one PDF page as the current VBA code leaves a lot of blank spaces within the PDF file.

**On each worksheet I have set the print area which is not a variable, So I'm assuming if there is a code to copy the print areas on selected sheets this would work perfectly.

```
Sub print_test()

 Dim strPath As String, strFileName As String

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Metadata", "BC on a page", "Approvals", "RMIB")).Select
 'Select file save location
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Show
 If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
 strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
 End If
 End With
 strFileName = InputBox("Please input filename", "Filename")
 strPath = strPath & "\"
 strFileName = strFileName & ".pdf"

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
 Type:=xlTypePDF, _
 Filename:=strPath & strFileName, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False

 Sheets("Metadata").Select
 End Sub
```

Comment: By default you can only print one `worksheet` to a PDF page. To print multiple `worksheets` to a PDF create another worksheet and link the information from the original sheet(s) to this sheet and print this sheet only to PDF. This sheet acts like a presentation sheet.

Comment: Okay I feared this would be the only option. Thanks for confirming